# changing innerHTMLs with a forEach() or map() loop not working reliably

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

This one may be unique, so I hope I can get a bit of insight here. I'm designing a node.js server web app which uses an HTML page and scripts to connect with Spotify's Web API. From the scripts/api, it returns an array, which I use in conjunction with a forEach() or map() loop (I tried both) to fill in these spaces in the HTML which are formatted like this:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
 <div class="user-img" id="recP1" style="background-image: url(images/orangeRedgrad.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="pl-3">
   <p class="name" id="recN1">No Song Name</p>
   <span class="position" id="recA1">No Artist Name .-.</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The code which fills in these ID spaces looks like this:

```
    .then(function (data) {
        var x = 1;
        trackURIs = [];
        console.log(data);
        data.tracks.forEach((data) => {
            //the three console.logs in this section are to show that the array received the data.
            console.log(x + ':');
            console.log(data.name);
            console.log(data.artists[0].name);
            trackURIs.push(data.uri);
            document.getElementById("recP" + x + "").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + data.album.images[0].url + ")";
            document.getElementById("recN" + x + "").innerHTML = data.name;
            document.getElementById("recA" + x + "").innerHTML = data.artists[0].name;
            x += 1;
        });
        //console.log(trackURIs);
    });
```

My problem is that the spaces for x=11 to x=20 will fill the first time someone gets recommendations, but each time after that, they will not change and leave the previous data there. When searching certain artists, they won't fill the first time even. My console shows that I have received the data, so I'm kind of stuck as to why 11-20 are unresponsive only sometimes.

This is true for both forEach() and map().

When changing the number of songs requested by the API (say from 20 -> 12), then the same will be true where only the first 10 are reliably changed by the code, whereas x=11 and x=12 may only change the first time and none after that or simply not at all.

[This image shows the 2nd run of a request for 12 song recommendations, where the first 10 are changed, but 11 and 12 are not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyCm1.png)

Comment: Why 20? Does the API return 20 every time? Or is the maximum 20?

Comment: The spotify API has an option which allows you to specify how many song recommendations you want. I set it to {limit: 20} to receive 20 songs. In addition, that's how many slots I have available on the webpage.

Comment: Okay cool. Limit is the max, but does your console.log prove that there's always 20? Because the API could respond with less.

Comment: Yes, when the limit is set at 20, console.log will print out all the data, which is why I had those three console.logs. They show perfectly the track number, song name, and artist name, but fail to add it to the HTML.

Comment: What I think is really funny is that even if the songs don't show on the webpage, you can press a "save to spotify" button and the track is still added in that playlist; proving the script is receiving that song's data perfectly.

Comment: Is that what trackURI[] is used for? And how are you generating the HTML, is it hard-coded in the HTML or do you build it? In the DOM viewer all the elements look correct?

Comment: On your second run, there is placeholder text in the results, how did that get there if on the first run it was filled?

Comment: yes to the trackURI question. the HTML is hard-coded with 20 slots where each of the ids change only by the number, so in slot 1 you have id="recP1" while in slot 13 you have id="recP13". I have no syntax errors, and all the IDs are correct.

Comment: That run was with a limit of 12 to show what it looks like without any data. so it got the 12 songs the first time then only posted 10 songs the second run.

Comment: Still the placeholder question, but also: your html snippet has an extra closing div tag. Is that a copy of the original?

Comment: But 2 songs have placeholders, so you filled 12, called the script again, and got 10, so how did the placeholders regenerate in the last 2?

Comment: Yes, but there's more Divs above it, I didn't mean to include that. The HTML doesn't have a problem as far as I can tell. It might be something with my CSS carousel though

Comment: The placeholders are hard-coded in the HTML with 20 slots. so that was slot 13 and slot 14, which remained unedited the whole time. I did not remove them when I set it to limit: 12

Comment: With your carousel, does it make any of these songs style display:none? Does that remove them from the DOM when the script runs?

Comment: The only thing that's display:none is the entire section that it's contained in. That display is changed when a user submits the song they want recommendations for and that section with the recommendations is revealed, with the recommendations there already.

I also found that slots 19 & 20 are filled with the song data, and if you space it correctly, slots 17 & 18 are filled with data until you go onto their "slide" of the carousel, in which it changes back to the placeholder like it doesn't exist, even though you can see it when dragging the carousel towards it.

Comment: to clarify, no, none of the placeholders are directly hidden with display: none

Comment: Can you remove the class names from your elements that make it into a carousel and see what happens? It'll be hideous, but it's for troubleshooting. I also wonder if their being hidden means the browser doesn't re-render or repaint them?

Comment: I hate having to admit this, but I just messed up one of the js scripts at the bottom which dealt with the carousel. It wasn't even posting in console, idk why, but I found it. It's cycling the carousel perfectly now. I apologize for taking your time for such a silly error, but thank you for pursuing into my problem. I appreciate it!

Comment: Haha, no worries, it's usually something like that. I pointed out someone's mix up today and they promptly deleted the question without a word.